# Avoid displaying tableview section header before table loads - ios - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a tableView added in storyboard with its datasource and delegates attached within storyboard

I have tableview section header "Pet Info" which display on one of the custom cell. As soon as i land on the screen, im reloading tableview data.

For a fraction of a second, my screen displays section header (before tableView.reloadData()).

How can i display my tableView only after data is available and not each time the user lands on screen . I don't want to add any spinner/shimmer screens.

I have a var hasPetInsurance = false by default which is loaded from API call and another var petData - loaded from another vc.

Now my header condition to display is if !hasNoPerInsurance && petData.count > 0 then display header - > header displays for a fraction of second because all my conditions are met before table reloads.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  if !hasNoPerInsurance && petData.count {
    showPetInfoHeader()
  } else {
    return nil
 }
}
```

is there any other way that i can acheive this?

Please advice

Comment: Why not just return 0 for `numberOfSections` if the source data array is empty?

Comment: Reason is I have data to display in viewModel but I display this cell when my precondition is met. Scenario is: I have a variable hasPetInsurance = false by default. which is loaded from API call and another variable petData - loaded from another vc. now my header condition to display is if  !hasNoPerInsurance && petData.count > 0 then display header - > header displays for a fraction of second because all my conditions are met before table reloads.

Comment: This could be a case for the rarely seen optional Bool.  Make `hasNoPetInsurance` an optional then it has three states - true, false and undetermined..